# Binary search tree question

Tags: combinatorics

Let $k_1,...,k_n$ be a sequence of pairwise distinct keys that arrive in this order and let $T$ be the corresponding binary search tree. Let $i<j$. Show that if $k_j$ is the left child of $k_i$, then $k_i$ is the smallest among those keys in $k_1,...,k_i$ that are greater than $k_j$.

So we have $k_1,...,k_i,...,k_j,...,k_n$ and $k_j < k_i$. Correct me if I am wrong but we are trying to prove that $\min \{k_1,...,k_i\}$ (such that $k_1,...,k_i>k_j$).

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assume for contradiction that there is an $l < j$ such that $k_i > k_l > k_j$. Then there are two cases

- There is an $l < i$ such that $k_i > k_l > k_j$. In this case, when it comes to placing $k_i$ in the binary tree, $k_i$ will end up in the right sub-tree of the first such $k_l$ it encounters as it searches through the tree, while $k_j$ will end up in the left sub-tree. $k_j$ can therefore not be a child of $k_i$.
- There is no such $l$. In that case, there must be an $l > i$. In this case, the largest such $k_l$ will end up in the left sub-tree of $k_i$ (possibly as a child, possibly further down), which means that when $k_j$ comes around to be placed, $k_i$ already has a left child. Therefore $k_j$ is not the left child of $k_i$.

Therefore, if $k_j$ is the left child of $k_i$, then $k_i$ has to be the smallest element before $k_j$ that is larger than $k_j$.